# Tracking locked rows using dm_tran_locks

Tags: azure-sql-database, locking, isolation-level

I use Azure SQL DB (Basic, DTU, Provisioned). Isolation is default read committed snapshot.

To handle concurrent transactions, I use table hints to lock the row(s). The requirement is that during the lock:

1. Other users should be allowed to read all the rows in the tables (including the one being updated).
2. Other users should be allowed to update other rows without waiting for the completion of the previous session.
3. Other users should be able to identify the lock details

   3.1 If Row1 is locked by User1, then other user should be able to identify the locked user and locked row.

   3.2 If Row1 is locked by User1, and, if Row2 is locked by User2, other user should be able to identify the locked users and the corresponding locked rows.

When I use `ROWLOCK` alone with `SELECT`, the requirements #1 and #2 are satisfied.

When I use `ROWLOCK,UPLOCK` with `SELECT`, the requirements #1 and #3.1 are satisfied (using `sys.dm_tran_locks` and `sys.dm_exec_sessions`).

Is there a way to satisfy #1, #2, #3.1 and #3.2?

Comment: You might want to look at snapshot isolation, which would satisfy 1 and 2 neatly

Comment: Cross-post from StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049496/azure-sql-db-handling-and-identifying-concurrent-transactions/68056853?noredirect=1#comment120323164_68056853